# join one table multiple times in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I've two tables for user and group member info. I am storing two user ids in `groupmember` table one as `group_userid` and another one as `group_memberid`. I want to join user table with `group_userid` and with `group_memberi`d. I've tried this query:

```
SELECT U.*, 
  S1.user_id as folusrid,
  S1.first_name,
  S1.last_name, 
  S2.user_id as follwginuserid,
  S2.first_name,
  S2.last_name 
FROM tbl_groupmemebers U 
JOIN tbl_user S1 ON (S1.user_id = U.group_userid) 
JOIN tbl_user S2 ON (S2.user_id = U.group_memberid) 
WHERE U.group_id = '2'
```

and got the result but the result is returning me in same row like this:

```
id    group_id    group_userid    group_memberid    group_joindate        folusrid    first_name        last_name    follwginuserid    first_name    last_name
3        2            18                11          2015-04-24 12:02:36     18        Mohammadshoaib    Swichmann           11           Clemen      Swichmann
```

I want the result in two separate columns.

Comment: `I want the result in two seperate columns.` elaborate more on this and perhaps with example.

Comment: Can u please properly format your output....

Comment: Do you mean two separate rows?

Comment: You mean two separate rows maybe? Cause you already getting them in separate columns

Comment: yes seperate rows sorry it was my mistake. output should be like this:-
id group_id group_userid group_memberid group_joindate folusrid first_name last_name follwginuserid 
3   2       18             11         2015-04-24 12:02:36 18     JAck Thomas 11 

4   2       18             11         2015-04-24 12:02:36 18     Clemen Swichmann 18

Comment: Note : `S2.last_name` appears twince in your select statement, you should have `S1.last_name`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this UNION

```
(
  SELECT U.*, 
    S1.user_id as user_id,
    S1.first_name,
    S1.last_name,
    'group_userid' as data_type
  FROM tbl_groupmemebers U 
  JOIN tbl_user S1 ON (S1.user_id = U.group_userid) 
  WHERE U.group_id = '2'
)
UNION ALL
(
  SELECT U.*, 
    S2.user_id as user_id,
    S2.first_name,
    S2.last_name,
    'group_userid' as data_type
  FROM tbl_groupmemebers U
  JOIN tbl_user S2 ON (S2.user_id = U.group_memberid) 
  WHERE U.group_id = '2'
);
```

This will give you one record for every U.group_userid and one record for every U.group_memberid. Use the 'data_type' column (the last one) to identify which one is what.

Comment: Thanks for your reply bro. there was some error in it but i've rectified it and its working fine now. i m accepting this as answer

Comment: Can you point the errors please? I would like to correct them.

Comment: Every derived table must have its own alias 
so for rectifying this error i've written query like this:-
select * from ( SELECT U.id,S1.user_id as user_id, S1.first_name, S1.last_name FROM tbl_groupmemebers U JOIN tbl_user S1 ON (S1.user_id = U.group_userid) where U.group_id = '1' UNION SELECT U.id, S2.user_id as user_id, S2.first_name, S2.last_name FROM tbl_groupmemebers U JOIN tbl_user S2 ON (S2.user_id = U.group_memberid) where U.group_id = '1') user_info